# Gremlin connection timeouts with Neptune

Tags: java, gremlin, amazon-neptune

I'm getting hundreds of thousands of these in our logs. I'm still querying and persisting data in Neptune, so not sure why this keeps popping up so often:

> Caused by: org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.remote.RemoteConnectionException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.exception.NoHostAvailableException: All hosts are considered unavailable due to previous exceptions. Check the error log to find the actual reason.

What could be the cause of this? I don't have anything beyond this to debug off of.

Tinkerpop client version `3.4.10`. Connection pool settings are whatever the default is because I'm not setting them:

```
        cluster =
            Cluster.build(hostName)
                .addContactPoint(hostName)
                .port(portNumber)
                .maxContentLength(maxContentLength)
                .channelizer(this.channelizer)
                .enableSsl(this.sslEnabled)
                .create()
```

Comment: Can you provide a bit more detail around how you are connecting to Neptune?  Is this via Lambda, how many queries are you running, how are you managing the connection, etc.

Comment: This is in a Kubernetes cluster on AWS. When the app boots up I make the connection once. I could have tens of queries per second

Comment: Do I need to close after every query or something and reinitialize the client?

Comment: Keeping the client open and reusing it between calls is definitely the way to go.  Have you taken a look at the best practices in the docs: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/neptune/latest/userguide/best-practices-gremlin-java-client.html

Comment: Yes, I've taken a look at these docs. Regarding https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/TINKERPOP-2569 might be part of the issue.

Comment: What version of the Java client are you using?  Can you update the post above with the version and the connection pool settings you are using?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233767/discussion-between-john-and-bechbd).